# What functions do the weights for the central difference stencils approximate?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

The central difference formula for the three-point stencil approximating the second derivative is given by
$$ f'' = \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}.$$

Similarly, for the five-point stencil, we have
$$ f'' = \frac{-f(x+2h)+16f(x+h)-30f(x)+16(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{12h^2}.$$

We can continue with the seven-point stencil, and so on. Here is a plot of the weights for the three-, five-, and seven-point stencils:[image]

It seems that these weights are approximating some wave function(s).

1. Is there a closed-form expression to generate the weights? What about the weights for the stencils of $f'$ or $f^{(n)})$?
2. Do these weights converge to some continuous function as the number of points $k$ tends to infinity?

Comment: There's a kind of nasty closed form in terms of the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix, which itself has a closed form but I don't know if it simplifies decently even with a uniform grid. The idea of the derivation is that for an $N+1$ point stencil $x+jh,x+(j+1)h,\dots,x+(j+N)h$, your equations read $\sum_{i=0}^{N} (i+j)^k w_i = n! h^{-k} \delta_{kn}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,N$. So the weights are $n! h^{-k}$ times one of the rows of the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix. The $j$ here is a shift based on the stencil; for centered stencils you would use $j=-N/2$ (where $N$ is even since $N+1$ is odd).

Comment: But even for the uniform grid this seems painful, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix

Comment: @Ian Do these wave functions converge to some continuous function as the number of points $k$ tends to infinity?

Comment: There is an excellent SIAM paper on computing these weights (and generalizations) - "Calculation of Weights in Finite Difference Formulas," by Bengt Fornberg. Here's a link to the citation at JSTOR - https://www.jstor.org/stable/2653239

Comment: Maybe asymptotically related to the Dirichlet kernel?

Comment: Regarding your question 2, in the paper (by Fornberg) https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/paper.pdf Tables 1 and 2 show the coefficients for 1st and 2nd derivatives as the stencil length goes to infinity. For example, for the 2nd derivative the kth coefficient is -2 (-1)^k/k^2, except for k=0, which is -pi^2/3. So there is a limiting form. (And a relation to the Dirichlet kernel sounds right.)

Comment: @TomDickens Thank you for the references. Regarding the Dirichlet kernel, it seems related but the Dirichlet kernel doesn't integrate to 0 or converge.

Comment: @user572780 - Yes, I was too hasty on the Dirichlet kernel; I was thinking of using the sinc function (looking at infinite-order as a spectral limit), as I wrote in my answer, which shows that the coefficients for the first derivative approach ..., -1/3, 1/2, -1, 0, 1, -1/2, 1/3, .... The same logic will work for the 2nd-derivative coefficients, which go like 1/n^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can approach the problem by using the sinc interpolation formula, thinking of the infinite-order finite-difference method as a spectral method. A band-limited function $y(x)$ can be written as a series based on its values at sample points $y(n h)$ , as
$$ y(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} y(n h)\  \text{sinc} ((x - n h)/h) $$
where the normalized sinc function is defined as
$ \text{sinc(u)}=\frac{\sin \pi u}{\pi u} $.

Then we can evaluate $y'(0)$ or $y''(0)$ by differentiating the series, for example for the first derivative, then evaluating it at
$x=0$, obtaining
$$y'(0) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} y(n h) \left[ \frac{ \sin (\pi  n)-\pi n \cos (\pi  n)}{\pi  h n^2} \right]. $$

Then, we see that the coefficients of the expansion of $ y'(0)$ are $-\cos(n \pi) / (h n) = (-1)^{n+1}/(n h)$, since $\sin(n \pi) = 0$, as the $n$ are integers. ($n=0$ is treated separately, by taking the limit as $n\rightarrow 0$, which shows that the coefficient for $n=0$ is 0.) The same argument works for the 2nd derivative.

EDIT:

For completeness, I'll add the result for the 2nd derivative. We have
$$y''(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} y(n h) \left[ -\frac{\left(h^2 \left(\pi ^2 n^2-2\right)-2 \pi ^2 h n x+\pi ^2 x^2\right) \sin \left(\pi  \left(n-\frac{x}{h}\right)\right)+2 \pi  h (h n-x) \cos \left(\pi  \left(n-\frac{x}{h}\right)\right)}{\pi  h (h n-x)^3}\right]. $$
Taking $x=0$, assuming $n \ne 0$ and an integer, gives the finite-difference coefficients $-\frac{2 (-1)^n}{h^2 n^2}$. For $n=0$ we take the limit of the coefficient expression at $x=0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$, which gives $ -\frac{\pi^2}{3 h^2} $. These coefficients are just those given in the second Fornberg paper I referenced in the comments,  http://colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/paper.pdf .